# WPF Binding a list to a ComboBoxColumn within a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, datagrid

I am having issues with a combo box within a data grid in WPF. Basically I have a class of "crew" and class of "user" and within the crew class is a list that contains all the member of that crew.

Ideally I want the data gird to have 3 columns "crew id", "members" and "status", The members column would be a combo box that can be click to show all the members of the crew. I'm able to bind the crews so that the id and status show fine but not the members.

The data grid is being bound in the constructor by a method that returns a list of all the crews.

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

```
        public ManagerDashboard(Dashboard Dash)
        {
            InitializeComponent();        
            dgCrew.ItemsSource = ds.listallCrews();
        }


//CREW CLASS
    public class Crew
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Datastore ds = new Datastore();       
        public List<OperationalUser> lstCrewMembers  { get; set; }
        public int Crewid { get { return GenId(); } }
        public bool bIsActive { get; set; }

        public Crew()
        {           
            bIsActive = true;
        }

        private int GenId()
        {
            int id = rnd.Next(0, 1000);

            foreach (User u in ds.ListAllUsers())
                if (id == u.Userid)
                    id = rnd.Next(0, 1000);

          
            return id;
        }
    }

//XMAL
<DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Crew ID"                                    
                                    Binding="{Binding Crewid}" />
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Members"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Crew, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                        DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding lstCrewMembers, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding lstCrewMembers.Userid}"
                                        SelectedValuePath="Userid"
                                        />
              
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Active"                                        
                                    Binding="{Binding bIsActive}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The DataGridComboBoxColumn is used for selecting from a list of types or so, that is common to all rows. You can probably create a list of ComboBoxItems from your list of members.
But I suggest that you use RowDetails to show your members, something like this:

```
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding lstCrewMembers}" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="UserId" Binding="{Binding Userid}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```